# What is the Japanese word that sounds like English word "Nonsense" and what is its meaning?

Tags: translation, spoken-language

I just heard a Japanese man say what sounded like "Nonsense" said with American accent immediately followed by Japanese "ka ne". Assuming he didn't throw a single American English word in his speech what is this Japanese word and its meaning? Sounds like "Nansenskane".

Answer (score 2):

This would be ナンセンス (nansensu), which means almost the same as English "nonsense". Daijirin also mentions ナンセンス文学 ("nonsense-literature"), which refers to the genre exemplified by Lewis Carroll. ([Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E6%96%87%E5%AD%A6) - links to English article ["Literary nonsense"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_nonsense))

Answer (score 2):

Without actually hearing it, my best guess as a native Japanese-speaker would be the colloquial:

> 「何{なん}すかね」 or 「何{なん}なんすかね」

The former is a contracted form of 「何{なん}**で**すかね」 and the latter, that of 「何{なん}なん**で**すかね」.

If 「で」 had actually been used, I do not think you would have missed it as the "d" consonant would have been pronounced fairly acutely in that context.

Finally, depending on the context, 「ナンセンスかね」 is also possible.